# Deleting directory trees in a OS-independent way in Perl 6

Tags: io, raku

I'm trying to clean up a set of directories after some tests, and do so in a way that's independent of the machine (and direct). I was using [`File::Directory::Tree`](https://github.com/labster/p6-file-directory-tree) but that wasn't working, throwing out weird errors. Instead, I tried:

```
method rm-cache() {
    if $*SPEC ~~ IO::Spec::Win32 {
        my $win-path = "$*CWD/$!path".trans( ["/"] => ["\\"] );
        shell "del $win-path\.lock";
        shell "rmdir /S /Q $win-path" ;
        shell "rmdir $win-path";
    } else {
        shell "rm -rf $!path";
    }
}
```

The Linux version works. The windows version, to which I came after 3 hours of tests, initially gave [some error about an existing lock](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/JJ/pod-to-cached/builds/27170208), which I'm deleting in the first shell sentence, without success, since it can't be removed.

- Where's the lock created and how can we get rid of it programmatically.
- There's better, and more Perl6y way, of doing that.

Comment: I never really thought about it but apparently the problem is non trivial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhRWMGBjlO8. There is a  C library named boost which offers platform independent file and directory functions. You could get your feet wet with NativeCall and write a binding for that.I'm sure it's a more pleasant experience than dealing with the windows API.

Comment: But if you're fine with shelling out, then you should know `rm` is not a Windows command. To delete a file one uses `del`.

Comment: Right. How dumb.

Comment: Windows does not let you delete files that have a handle open, so don't try to delete directories that contains stuff you have open handles to (such as precomp files that have had `.load` called on them for some reason, or the open directory lock files)

Comment: @ugexe I could figure as much, the thing is that the operation was done at the end of a program and I couldn't find a way of closing those handles and actually deleting those directories that were actually no longer needed.

Comment: Are you under the impression that the last line of your code is the end of the program doing anything?

Comment: @ugexe, no, it's not, but I need the program to clean up after itself, which is why I'd need to close stuff so that I can delete the temporary files I've created. Come to think of it, it might be better to actually use temporary files...

Comment: As I've noted in other answers before: using `.load` to precompile stuff is wrong. I'm guessing your issue is with cargo culted code that sets up (what I assume is) the precompiled document cache, which leaves you loading code and locking directories from the same location you are trying to delete from while still running.

Comment: @ugexe what would be the right way to precompile stuff then?

Comment: Sure looks like it calls `.precomp`, so what is the purpose of calling `.load` in the first place?